# Program doesn't compile after creating NSManagedObject subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, core-data

When I'm creating NSManagedObject subclasses the programme doesn't want to compile with one uncategorized error -

```
"Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code"
```

and also creates errors one for each subclass file saying that "

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataError-cqtxdlgmsibvltbxuxzvrapubhlp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CoreDataError.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataError.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Person+CoreDataProperties.o':
```

Here is my data model.
[image]
[image: My data model]

This is error log
[image]

I tried to change build settings to Legacy Build System, but it didn't help also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift CoreData NSManagedObject subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390820/swift-coredata-nsmanagedobject-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, this happens when you actually indeed create NSManagedObject classes (or their properties) twice.

In your case, you have created the code for the classes Friend and Person thanks to the Editor menu command. Then you have integrated those modules into your project. So the compiler compile those classes.

BUT

Most probably, you have not changed the CoreData class generation option. You can find this option in the CoreData pane of the inspector (Class section, Codegen menu). It can take 3 values : "Manual/None" "Class Definition" or "Category/extension".

I guess you have stayed with the default "Class Definition", which means that when XCode compiles your model, it temporarily generates swift modules for each of your entity, and compiles those modules. You therefore end up with 2 modules named "Friend" and 2 modules named "Person". Therefore the error.

You want to use editor generated modules, most probably because you want to modify them, then you should set the Codegen menu to either "Manual / None" or "Category / extension".
You can do that on a per-entity basis.

Some consistent use cases :

- You have an entity, and you just don't want to touch anything : keep "Class Definition" as Codegen ooption and don't generate the class code with the editor, let XCode do everything.
- You have an entity, and you want to modify it, for example, you want to add some awakeFromInsert manual code. However, you want XCode to keep generating accessors for attributes when you change them. Generate the code for the module, include it in you project (but not the extension for the attributes), modify it, but keep "Category / extension" as a generation option.
- You want to manage everything yourself : generate the entity code once, include it in your project, and choose "Manual / None". Now take care that when you change some attributes/relations, you need to maintain the code in synch manually.